# Geotool Shapefile onto Unfolding Maps

Tags: shapefile, geotools

Are there any ways to add a Shapefile layer using Geotools onto a map which created by Unfolding Maps? Or do I need to convert the shapefile(.shp) into other forms first?

Comment: what is an Unfolding Map?

Comment: Unfolding Library [link](http://unfoldingmaps.org/)

Comment: They talk about it [here](http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/markers-data-geojson). Yes, you do need to convert the shapefile.